# Heroku bad line length failed to push some refs

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to upload changes to Heroku via:

```
git commit -am "make it better"
git git push heroku master:main
```

Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 81926.25 MiB/s   
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/purgescan.git'
```

I don't understand why because It seems to write like 4 GB worth of objects and I'm not sure why. I can't pull any changes, and nothing I do seems to fix this.

I tried to commit a 7 GB file (to train my machine learning model), but it failed. But for some reason I think Heroku thinks I did commit the file or something, but I can't do anything about since It won't let me commit changes.

I did `git add <<7GB NLP training file>>`, then I did `git commit` and `git push`.

Comment: I really hope you aren't actually using "make it better" as a commit message...

Comment: "It seems to write like 4 GB worth of objects"—How large do you expect your repository to be? Heroku limits a checked out working copy to be 1 GB, and limits the compiled slug size to 500 MB.

Comment: Well, I don't have anything huge in my repository, I tried to commit a 7 GB file (to train my machine learning model), but it failed. But for some reason I think heroku thinks I did commit the file or something, but I can't do anything about since It won't let me commit changes

Comment: "I tried to commit a 7 GB file (to train my machine learning model), but it failed. But for some reason I think heroku thinks I did commit the file or something"—well, did you commit it, or did you _try to_ commit it? What do you mean by "it failed"? "It won't let me commit changes"—committing is done by `git commit`, not `git push`. Did the `git commit` succeed?

Comment: Also yes XD, I do use "make it better" as a commit message lol. I'll do the same thing when I work as a developer lmao.

Comment: "I'll do the same thing when I work as a developer lmao"—please _don't_. I'd never let anybody get away with commit messages like that on my team. Commit messages are worth spending some time on.

Comment: Well I did `.git add <<7GB NLP training file>>`  Then I did git commit and git push. And it gave me an error. So I thought I didn't push because it's way too big.

Comment: ""I'll do the same thing when I work as a developer lmao"—please don't. " Lmao, but yeah, I understand the importance of commit messages, when i'm alone though I don't care too much, although it usually ends up biting me in the ass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to commit a 7 GB file (to train my machine learning model), but it failed. But for some reason I think Heroku thinks I did commit the file or something, but I can't do anything about since It won't let me commit changes.

Committing and pushing are different things. Your *push* is failing, but that doesn't mean the commit failed. It isn't that "Heroku thinks" you committed the file; you actually committed the file.

Your repository almost certainly shouldn't contain a 7GB data file. I suggest you remove it. You'll have to actually remove the entire commit, otherwise it will still be in your repository's history and contribute to its size.

Assuming the commit you need to remove is the last one on your branch (make sure to look at your log and graph), you should be able to do something like this:

1. First, discard the latest commit on the current branch:

   ```
    git reset --hard HEAD~
   ```
2. Then, push that change to Heroku (assuming your remote is called `heroku`):

   ```
    git push --force-with-lease heroku
   ```

If you want that file to still be in your working directory you might want to add it to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ran git reset --hard HEAD~ but for now it is currently executing, so hopefully it's working. Will verify answer once it finishes executing. Also, do I have to run `git push --force-with-lease heroku` after git reset?

Comment: @SalvorHardin, yes, you need to do both steps. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: It doesn't work, I ran `git push --force-with-lease heroku` but it still says : `fatal: protocol error: bad line length 2457689 MiB/s   
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/purgescan.git'` I'm not sure why, I ran the git reset command a couple times. Is there any way I can check the repo to see what is in it and what is causing the problem?

Comment: "I ran the git reset command a couple times—why would you do that?! That's not an idempotent command: "reset your local branch to the previous commit". You can't run it over and over and expect not to break something. Check your Git log. You are likely several commits back now, and you may have to use the reflog to fix your repository.

Comment: You're going to have to edit a bunch more info into your question. Please show the log, the commit where you introduced the 7 GB file, the commit you actually want to deploy, and the commit `heroku/main` or `heroku/master` is on.

Comment: How do I check the git log? (Am a big github noob). I ran it many times because I ran it once, tried to push force but it didn't do anything, so I just went back again.

Comment: It sounds like you need a Git tutorial. Looking at your log is one of the most basic things you can do: `git log`. You should be using this command regularly. "I ran it many times because I ran it once, tried to push force but it didn't do anything, so I just went back again"—I hope you've learned not to do that.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much! This whole problem was caused by my lack of rigor. It won't happen again! I am determined.

Comment: Glad to hear it!